# Real time editor for Cloud Storage System

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cloud

I am working on cloud storage system in ASP.Net MVC5. In which I made a file manager that handles cut,copy,download multiple files,edit and preview of files, but I want to edit documents like word files in real time (collaborative editing)..is there any api that can help me accordingly.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let me just confirm if I understand your goal correctly. You look at a word file and see changes another user is making in real time?
MS Office does boast to have such functionality, but I doubt it's open for coders to use. If you want to do this thing with multiple file types, you better start writing your own code. Collaborative editing isn't exactly new, but each developer adjusts to files they are working with and I doubt you will find an API that can work with all files.

Comment: yes i want to this with multiple file but i cannot find editor that support such functionalities...

Comment: Says [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Simultaneously-edit-a-document-with-other-authors-2a6059e7-9fe9-4e66-8ecd-f3d5372c27f4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) that you can simultaneously edit .docx files that are on OneDrive or a server with SharePoint Server installed.

Comment: i want APi (with source code) that can easily fit in ASP.NET MVC 5 without moving to any  other website..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use Signal R for real time applications...it may be possible with the help of application user interface but its better to write your own code according to your choice...

[http://signalr.net/][1]

dev_express and syncfusion may be your solution..try these..

Answer (score 0):

This is turning into a huge comment, so I'll just explain my point of view in an answer. I'll remove it, if I see an actual answer appears.

I am suggesting you start writing your own code for collaborative editing and the reason is quite simple. You need at least slightly different processing for almost each file type, **which suggests there will never be a single API to support collaborative editing for all file types**, unless somebody makes it their goal to maintain it and keep up with every one created.

Start it simple, text (or hex) editing. Define how changes are made and implemented on other clients and then work your way to add as many file types (and methods that go with them) as you need.

You could use source code of 1 of these [open source collaborative text editors](https://opensource.com/business/15/7/five-open-source-alternatives-google-docs) (you'll have to find download / Github links on their websites) to get a general idea how to do it, but you will still have to put in some work and won't go far without creating your own code.

---

Collaborative editing requires user 1's (who just started editing) client to send either one of these:

1. Data pointing to changes made in file
2. Full file, and user 2's client (or central "server") should be able to calculate the changes made from there and implement them.

One of the problems is to overwrite only that portion of the file changes were made to (and avoid overwriting the other user 2's work).

And the biggest problem (the reason you can't have "1 for all" method/API)  is each file type has its own structure meaning that different file types will have different data representing changes in file. If you try to write raw data it might work, but you'd still need to calculate and lock away specific portions of file, that contain general information, rather than data of your file.

Comment: actually i am new to collaborative editing ASP.NET MVC 5.please tell me  if you know any api suporting only single file type.beacuse currently i am not in position to write my own code regarding this problem..thankx